# How to conditionally add a text to a component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add this line that says that the ninja is a master but only if the belt is red or black. I think I'm mixing up this type of function I'm trying to use.

```
<div>{isMaster = () => {
    if (n.belt === "black" || n.belt === "red") {
       return "Master";
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one line. Don't create a function there

```js
<div>{(n.belt === "black" || n.belt === "red") && "Master"}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
  {(n.belt === "black" || n.belt === "red") && "Master"}
</div>
```